# Any disadvantages of using JQTouch/Phonegap over Android API?

Tags: android, cordova, jqtouch, tablet

Are there any main disadvantages of using JQTouch/Phonegap to put together Android Apps / Tablet Apps rather than using the Android API.

I basically want to program an app for a client that will sell music (connect to existing PHP site) and use geographical info to show bands/gigs close by - again via  interrogation of their current PHP site.

I have years of Jquery experince and good HTML5/css3 knowledge so JQtouch/Phonegap would be the most straightforward option, but just wanted to make sure I'm not heading down the wrong path!

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see for your self. [Comparison Chart](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AsTInFQpmXDNdEdJU0ZNNGx3dDA3aXAxV3lXYWhXVHc) .I would any day go with Android SDK over Phonegap. In your case you can use Phonegap. Are you planing to deploy it on iOS too ?