# Is PhoneGap a good choice for App Development?

Tags: android, cordova

I am a new iOS Developer, but knows nothing about Android development and Java at this moment. I am going to invest time in learning a tool to develop Android version of apps. PhoneGap sounds powerful for its cross-platform ability, but I am not sure if there are any drawbacks. Could anyone tell me the pros and cons of using PhoneGap? Based on your experience, would you suggest me to go for native Android or PhoneGap? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: [Mark Zuckerberg: "Our Biggest Mistake Was Betting Too Much On HTML5"](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/11/mark-zuckerberg-our-biggest-mistake-with-mobile-was-betting-too-much-on-html5/). My opinion is that the HTML5 apps are really slow in Android.

Comment: your experience is similar to ottel's answer down here.

Comment: @BraisGabin I can see why zuckerbeeg would say that considering the current, highly polished state of the Facebook app. You could never get that level of performance without going native. However, since this is three years later,  do you know anything about the more recent gsp between mobile web and native? I am looking for the same answer as OP but I think phones are more powerful and phone gap must have improved as well during this time.

Comment: @user137717 this is just my opinion: if you are an experienced web developer then Cordova is fine. You can develop an app using all that knowledge. But the user experience is worst than a native app. If you don't have this experience Cordova is pointless. I recommend you check different apps and you then can decide if it's good enough.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I've been developing with Phonegap quite a while ago.
`NOTE: this is all based on my own experience`

#### Pro's:

- You don't need any 'native' experience, only intermediate 'web development skills' will be enough.
- For 95% you don't have to worry if it'll work on both iOS and Android, because Phonegap does all your worries, Just use the Phonegap Libs.
- As for my experience, for iOS it is really easy and fast to test.

  - Another part of my team was building the 'android version'. Don't worry, you don't need to. That was a personal choice. In the end we merged everything together and only needed rechecks on a few things. (e.g. different layouts on different pages. See the **Cons** for more about this.)

#### Cons

- You have to think about the buttons you are going to use. Android devices have an own 'back' button. As for iOS you need to develop this in your application. This is a choice of your own, but you might ending up designing two pages.
- Performance wise Phonegap is not the best.. I cannot tell you the exact reason for this, core-wise. Our application didn't need a highly graphical interface, but Phonegap seemed to struggle with 'decent' webpages already. So, when you are planning to build a game or some app that needs high graphical performance, you'd better go native.

#### Then I did some quick research for you.

- [Here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AsTInFQpmXDNdEdJU0ZNNGx3dDA3aXAxV3lXYWhXVHc) I found a nice mobile framework comparison. (via [this SO q.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927564/any-disadvantages-of-using-jqtouch-phonegap-over-android-api))
- [Here](http://www.sapandiwakar.in/api-research-study-iphone-and-android-applications/) is a really well-written article comparing **Titanium**, **Phonegap** and **Native** application development.
- [Here](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/phonegap-app-development-pros-cons) are pro's and cons listed.

Binding all together, it really depends on the purpose of your application.
When designing a game or other application that needs high graphical performance, you'd better go native programming.
When you are planning to build a light weight application and you already have web development knowledge, I recommend Phonegap.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and your share of experience. I have got some foundations to make decision now.

Comment: How about licenses and such. I am looking to write a Hybrid App for a "Student's University Project" where there will be no aim at publishing.
SumUp - Is PhoneGap free?

Comment: And can I write to my IOS device (Ipad) without getting involved in lincensing?

Comment: @Sonaten, "PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about." - www.PhoneGap.com
You cannot test your developed code on an Apple device without a provisioning key. As this (http://bit.ly/w0IfYH) SO q. is answered.

Comment: For games you could go with Unity3D for cross platform app

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for a tool to develop Android version of apps which already exist? So cross-platform ability, which is a key benefit, won't be used?

I'd recommend you to invest some time in native Android development. You are probably familiar with Objective-C, getting into JAVA won't be a tough task. Native apps get better ratings than web apps because of their consistent look (buttons and other layout components) and way better performance. PhoneGap apps run enjoyable on iOS devices but lag even on dual-core Androids like the Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Getting started:

- [Android SDK Download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- [Eclipse IDE Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1)
- [Google's Getting Started Training](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, your experience on Samsung is special. May I know what kind of app you were developing that make it lagging?

Answer (score 4):

I have just gone through coming from scratch into trying both native Android and Phonegap. Phonegap can be a good idea if you want to do something on Android which does not require specific phone features not covered by phonegap (because otherwise you will be both working on phonegap and android native for developing phonegap plugins =D).

On the other hand, Android introduces a bit of complexity on the management of the Activity lifecycle which you do not need to worry when you use phonegap.

So, if you do not need a very complex application, but something that could pretty much work well as if it was a simple web application, or if all phone features you need are supported by phonegap, phonegap is perhaps the preferred choice (specially if you are already familiar with web development).

Ah, and off course, you cant expect a phonegap application to have the same performance as a native one. But again, if your performance requirements are not too high, it is perhaps worth considering phonegap.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

phonegap works as a native webview with some access to main native features such as gestures camera....
using it you can do whatever you can do in any web app in addition to native features....
so its all depending on your app and what you really want to do