# what tasks can not be done using phonegap for android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I just started learning Phonegap.
I went through this [tutorials](http://phonegap.com/blog/tag/tutorial) .
Now I got one question in my little mind.. 
I just want to know what are the tasks can not be done using phonegap for Android. 
I searched a lot on this question but I found [this kind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439705/is-phonegap-a-good-choice-for-app-development) solutions on pros and cons of phonegap, and those are not answers to satisfy my mind.
please anybody provide relevant solution.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very simple words PhoneGap based on a native WebView with some Cordova API (A javascript bridge).
That means that you can call functions from the WebView to your native code and in oposite direction.
So that means that you can do anything that the native can do.
Because you question is too abstract I would say again that you can do anything like native, but for functionality that is not appear in Cordova API you will need to implement buy yourself (native) using Javascript bridge (for Android and IOS).
I hope that satisfy your mind.